# How can I search patterns in Screen with a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, gnu-screen

I have a process which gives me continuously output in Screen. I want to search CamelCase words by the following Perl's regex in the output such that I can monitor actively the outputs.

```
/\b([a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*){2,}\b/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tested in GNU/Screen and checked the source code. Both suggest that this is not possible. The search feature appears to support basic string matching only.

What I suggest is that you use the `tee` command to send your program's output to a file in addition to printing it. You can use Perl or grep on the file after that.

```
$ your_program | tee your_program_output
$ grep pattern your_program_output
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! - - Did you see that it is not possible at $man screen?

Comment: Hmm, I can't find this in the man page. I'm using version 4.0.3.

Comment: @ayman: What is your default search in Screen? I ask it because I cannot get my default search work at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by default search. Here is what I do to search the scroll buffer:

* Press ctrl+a esc.
* Press ? to search backwards.
* Enter a search string and hit enter.

I don't have anything special for search in my screenrc. It is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, capture the output and search that. gnu/screen isn't the right tool for capturing data and plenty of things can go wrong with this. But obviously you can still run it inside a screen session.

Answer (score 1):

if you have already run the program inside screen without tee and prefer not to run it again, [assuming your scrollback buffer is large enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8760346/463138), you can [copy the entire scrollback buffer to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6604296/463138) and then search with your favorite method.