# Copying the GNU screen scrollback buffer to a file (extended hardcopy)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

How do I easily copy the GNU Screen scrollback buffer to a file? I.e., a more powerful version of the 'hardcopy' command?

In GNU screen, I can use "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>" to enter the scrollback
buffer. I could then mark the entire buffer and use "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>" to paste it into an [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) buffer, thus saving it to a file.

However, this is tedious. Is there a Screen command that'll simply copy the scrollback buffer to a file, like 'hardcopy' does for the visible portion of the screen?

Answer (score 378, accepted):

To write the entire contents of the scrollback buffer to a file, type

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>:</kbd>
to get to command mode, then

path: location where you want to save the screen log file.

```
hardcopy -h <path/filename>
```

Example:

```
hardcopy -h <home/admin/myScreen.log>
```

In older versions of `screen`, if you just do `hardcopy -h`, it just writes to the file `-h`. This was fixed in version 4.2.0, so `hardcopy -h` writes to `hardcopy.N` where **`N`** is the current window number.

Comment: Note that the file gets saved in the home directory -- at least it did for me. Thanks for the answer, btw!

Comment: @allrite: It gets saved in $PWD (if you don't give fullpath), there is no special behavior.

Comment: Yes, but it gets saved in the $PWD where you *started* screen. *Not* in the screen session's $PWD.

Comment: Note that if you have a long scrollback buffer and not much in it, the saved file may appear empty because the first tens or hundreds of lines are blank and the content is at the end.

Comment: One further note about the location where the hardcopy gets saved: If you cd to a directory and then use `screen -r` to reconnect to an existing session, the hardcopy doesn't get saved to the active directory inside screen or the one you were in before using `screen -r`. I think it gets saved to the directory you were in when you first started the screen session. You may be able to change this with the [hardcopydir](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_17.html#SEC101) command.

Comment: Just a comment - not everything that runs inside screen is a shell (or has a PWD). Screen supports serial consoles where a local directory makes no sense, so it's possible that there's only one directory involved - the one that the screen process started in.

Comment: If you're not sure about the directory, create a new window with Ctrl+A+C. It opens in the directory where the file is saved.

Comment: Note that unlike the methods which involve the copy buffer, the `hardcopy` command dumps the scrollback exactly as it appears, including breaking long lines for the current terminal width. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: In addition to the tip from @SeppoEnarvi, screen's working can be determined with a good ol' `pwd` command to the parent shell: **Ctrl+a :** `!pwd` .

Comment: This strips ANSI color codes before saving to file. Is there any way to preserve them?

Comment: Thanks @Murphy'sProphet. I tried various methods but couldn't find the log file. This command saves my day.

Comment: I successfully did `screen -S mysession -X hardcopy -h /tmp/buffer.txt` and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 27):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> **:bufferfile /tmp/somefile.txt** <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>></kbd>

This will write the current contents of the buffer to the named file.

Comment: I tried this, and the "ctrl-a >" says "Nothing happened". The first step did say "Bufferfile is now '/tmp/foo.txt'", but doesn't appear to even create that file.

Comment: Are you sure you had copied something into the screen buffer using Ctrl+A [?  It sounds like your buffer might be empty - it won't copy the entire scrollback buffer, just the portion you selected using Ctrl+A [

Comment: Ah, I was looking for a shortcut to copy the entire buffer without using ctrl-a [

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR: `^A:writebuf <filename>`

The OP seems to want a way to use the selected portion of the buffer you get when doing a ^A[ , selecting text using space as the start and finish, and then instead of using ^A] to paste, save the resulting selected portion of the buffer to a file.

This worked:

`^A:writebuf <filename>`

Note: one 'f' in writebuf

Comment: No, no. OP wants to save the ENTIRE buffer, not just the selected part. - OP

Comment: Rats! Missed it by this much

Comment: This post is still useful. Good job.

Comment: I found that to make this work on MacOSX version of screen I had to use an abolute path (i.e: /Users/user1/path/to/file.txt)

Answer (score 6):

Try `hardcopy -h` to include the whole buffer.

Comment: This just makes a hardcopy in the file ~/-h

Comment: @barrycarter: That may have changed in more recent versions. As of screen 4.03.01, `hardcopy -h` writes to `hardcopy.N`, where `N` is the current window number.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

Enter edit mode (`~`) and type:

```
:hardcopy -h buff_file
```

It created a huge file, of which 98% was empty, but my logs were fully present in remaining 2%.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, and issue the command 'log on'.

Or set it as the default in your *.screenrc* file as 'deflog on'.

Comment: I think this just starts logging everything after I run that 
command. I don't want to log everything (too verbose). I just want to 
capture the scrollback buffer as a file.

Answer (score -3):

Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>.

That saves the current screen into a hard copy file, e.g., hardcopy.0 for screen 0. It seems to be a quicker way than going <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd> and typing the *hardcopy* command.

Comment: Unfortunately, that just saves the VISIBLE portion of the screen, not the scrollback buffer.