# Save Screen (program) output to a file

Tags: logging, buffer, dump, gnu-screen

I need to save the whole output of [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) to a file to check later all the content.

The reason is that I'm dumping a flash memory through a serial port, using Screen to interface with it. I would like to save it to a file to check memory structure.

I've tried:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 >> foo.txt
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 | tee foo.txt
```

And I've also tried to use bufferfile from screen, but I don't understand how to use it.

Is there an easy way?

Comment: The production setting I am using has multiple instances of screen. The one whose output I need has line as 'pts/10'. Hence what should I do to obtain its output to a file?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

There is a command line option for logging. The output is saved to screenlog.n file, where n is a number of the screen.
From man pages of screen:

> ‘-L’ Tell screen to turn on automatic output logging for the windows.

Comment: Thanks. Is there is a way to output what screen already has in its output buffer? E.g. I forgot to enable logging, but output is available in the scroll screen buffer - how to write that to a file?

Comment: Just googled a bit more.. Here's answer for my repvious comment - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807474/copying-gnu-screen-scrollback-buffer-to-file-extended-hardcopy
Ctrl+A and :
to get to command mode, then

    hardcopy -h <filename>

in case somebody elsee will need this.

Comment: Log file will be created in the same directory in which you executed screen.

Comment: Yesterday I did a "screen -L", disconnected my SSH session, logged in again today and reattached using "screen -r" (I only had one), exited, and did a `find / -name "screen*log"` which found nothing.

Comment: related: [Is it possible to name the screen logfile from the L flag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026184/is-it-possible-to-name-the-screen-logfile-from-the-l-flag)

Comment: I use -r to reconnect to my screen instance. Hence when I try to do screen -rL instance, it didn't log the output. Also, my screen is multiple instance but I want output of only one instance, how to achieve this?

Comment: Is there way to specify the logfile that should be augmented?

Comment: This did nothing for me

Comment: @pacoverflow It appears that `screen` deletes the log file upon exiting.  If you want to save the logfile, copy it before you exit `screen` (detaching and reattaching should not clear the logfile)

Answer (score 141):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> to save loggings into a *screenlog.n* file.

And one more <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> to turn it off.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>: Begins/ends logging of the current window to the file "screenlog.n".

Comment: +1. If the log can’t be created, then try changing the screen window’s working directory: Ctrl-`a` + `:` and type for example `chdir /home/foobar/baz`

Comment: C-a + H just switches screen windows for me. Nothing to do with a log file!

Comment: @aaa90210 It's ctrl-a followed by a separate press of h for a hardcopy. ctrl-a followed by a separate press of shift-h starts a complete log file.

Comment: Looking for the screenlog.0 file created by Ctrl-a H?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198881/where-can-i-find-the-screenlog-0-file

Answer (score 64):

The following command works for Screen version 4.06.02:

```
screen -L -Logfile Log_file_name_of_your_choice command_to_be_executed
```

From the [man page of Screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen):

```
-Logfile file : By default logfile name is "screenlog.0".
                You can set new logfile name with the "-Logfile" option.
```

You can check the existing version of *Screen* using **screen -version**. You can download and install the latest *Screen* version from https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/.

Comment: Also you can leave the command_to_be_executed as blank and enter a series of long running jobs

Comment: Remember to have write permissions to screen's working directory, because otherwise it fails silently (simply not logging without any warning)

Comment: Looks like this command was depreciated and is no longer part of CLI

Answer (score 26):

The selected answer doesn't work quite well with multiple sessions and doesn't allow to specify a custom log file name.

For multiple screen sessions, this is my formula:

1. Create a configuration file for each process:

   ```
   logfile test.log
   logfile flush 1
   log on
   logtstamp after 1
   logtstamp string "[ %t: %Y-%m-%d %c:%s ]\012"
   logtstamp on
   ```

   If you want to do it "on the fly", you can change `logfile` automatically.
   `\012` means "new line", as using `\n` will print it on the log file: [source](http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/07/gnu-screen-logtstamp-string.html).
2. Start your command with the "-c" and "-L" flags:

   ```
   screen -c ./test.conf -dmSL 'Test' ./test.pl
   ```

   That's it. You will see "test.log" after the first flush:

   ```
   ...
   6 Something is happening...
   [ test.pl: 2016-06-01 13:02:53 ]
   7 Something else...
   [ test.pl: 2016-06-01 13:02:54 ]
   8 Nothing here
   [ test.pl: 2016-06-01 13:02:55 ]
   9 Something is happening...
   [ test.pl: 2016-06-01 13:02:56 ]
   10 Something else...
   [ test.pl: 2016-06-01 13:02:57 ]
   11 Nothing here
   [ test.pl: 2016-06-01 13:02:58 ]
   ...
   ```

I found that "-L" is still required even when "log on" is on the configuration file.

I couldn't find a list of the time format variables (like %m) used by screen. If you have a link of those formats, please post it bellow.

#### Extra

In case you want to do it "on the fly", you can use this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $2 == "" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 name command";
    exit 1;
fi
name=$1
command=$2
path="/var/log";
config="logfile ${path}/${name}.log
logfile flush 1
log on
logtstamp after 1
logtstamp string \"[ %t: %Y-%m-%d %c:%s ]\012\"
logtstamp on";
echo "$config" > /tmp/log.conf
screen -c /tmp/log.conf -dmSL "$name" $command
rm /tmp/log.conf
```

To use it, save it (screen.sh) and set +x permissions:

```
./screen.sh TEST ./test.pl
```

... and will execute ./test.pl and create a log file in /var/log/TEST.log

Comment: Thank you - the `on-the-fly` part is super useful.

Comment: Following up, a screen run overnight with a config file created and deleted on the fly errored out on a `screen -r` with `"Unable to open "/tmp/log.conf"`. Also, the screen went from `[detached]` state to non-existent. What could have been the problem?

Comment: What does your command do? screen will recreate the log file when missing, so I'm guessing /tmp/ run out of space or had some other OS related problem? I use this approach in several servers which run indefinitely and so far I haven't seen such situation in at least 1 year. If you want we can start a chat and I can help you to debug your problem.

Comment: It was over an SSH and disconnected so I had to log in again. Could that have anything to do with this? For the moment I save the conf file to the `pwd` as well, so it's working OK.

Comment: My command runs a long pipeline which uses our cluster to run a whole lot of jobs, but I don't think that had anything to do with this.

Comment: You said before, the screen went from [detached] to non-existent. The only situation I know for that to happen is that your process exited (could be a crash, fatal error, connection lost, etc). Better to check logs and see if there is any clue in them. The only solution I can think of, is to be sure that no matter what, the child process would never exit (wrap it in a infinite-loop script).

Comment: Hmmm, the process did error out. However, I rarely start a `screen` detached. I usually give it a `-c`, a `-L` and a `-S` then run commands inside the screen so it shouldn't terminate no matter what happens to the child process, right?

Comment: I think you are right, it should no terminate the screen if you are running the process that way, which is the same as executing: `screen bash`. If any other process is killing your screen, it should be listed as 'dead', but no disappear. I'm not sure what can it be.

Comment: Never mind, I just save the conf file as `$(pwd)/${name}.screenrc` and the  log file as `$(pwd)/${name}.screenlog` and that works fine (I think) although I see a brief error flash - I'll try and catch that the next time I start a screen.

Comment: It just happened again! If I try and attach a detached `screen` whose `screenrc` file has been moved, the screen just terminates. This one terminated in the middle of a process :(

Comment: `'$name'` should probably be quoted in double quotes: `"$name"`

Comment: @qräbnö : Nice catch! All this time and I didn't notice it. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This made me realize -- somewhere between screen versions `4.03.01` and `4.06.02`, the argument order matters. Whereas before I had `-dmLS` as the flags, that no longer worked on `4.06.02`. Changing it to `-dmSL` as per this example, it works like a charm again.

Answer (score 25):

The existing screen log can be saved by:

<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> hardcopy -h filename

Comment: Should I while standing with the session?

Answer (score 19):

For the Mac terminal:

```
script -a -t 0 out.txt screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

#### Details

- `script`: A built-in application to "make a typescript of terminal session"
- `-a`: Append to output file
- `-t 0`: Time between writing to output file is 0 seconds, so out.txt is updated for every new character
- `out.txt`: Is just the output file name
- `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`: Command from question for connecting to an external device

You can then use [tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) to see that the file is updating.

```
tail -100 out.txt
```

Comment: This did not work for me on a Mac. The log file shows the script starting the common and the command ending, but not the data received from the screen command.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> then <kbd>Shift+H</kbd> works for me. You can view the file `screenlog.0` while the program is still running.

Comment: Ctrl+A then H  .

Comment: @ShimonDoodkin I tried that, for some reason doesn't work on Debian. Might be helpful to others though. Thanks!

Comment: @jaggedsoft where is that file is created? which path?

Answer (score 13):

A different answer if you need to save the output of your whole scrollback buffer from an already actively running screen:

```
Ctrl-a [ g SPACE G $ >.
```

This will save your whole buffer to /tmp/screen-exchange

Comment: This post[1] offers a simpler solution: `Ctrl + a`, then `:` to get to command mode, and then `hardcopy -h <filename>`

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6604296/1734789

Answer (score 8):

Here's a trick: wrap it in `sh -c`!

```
screen sh -c './some-script 2>&1 | tee mylog.log'
```

Where `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout so `tee` can catch and log error messages.

Answer (score 7):

The 'script' command under Unix should do the trick. Just run it at the start of your new console and you should be good.

Comment: great! where does it print it?

Comment: It should just writes to a file. Command is a bit messy but I think this might solve that a bit: http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/279/record-the-terminal-session-and-replay-later/

Answer (score 6):

The following might be useful (tested on: Linux/[Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin)):

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Using the above, you can then do all the re-directions that you need. For example, to dump output to your console while saving to your file, you'd do:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | tee console.log
```

Comment: This one worked for me perfectly. I'm logging serial monitor output from an Arduino data capture session.

Answer (score 1):

It cost me a lot to find a clean solution. Although previous replies are fine, I found out this to be more direct.

This command will wait 5 seconds to write the output to a file. The 'sudo' part depends of your environment.

```
screen -dm bash -c 'sleep 5;echo "done" | sudo tee ./test.txt'
```

Comment: What is the significance of the 5 seconds? Why is it necessary?