# Log the result of a command to a serial port

Tags: logging, serial-port, tty

I don't even know if I'm asking this the right way, but hopefully I can be clear enough.

I'm using a piece of hardware connected to a raspberry pi (it is a USB charging hub).  The hub has a set of commands that can be run on it, such as "l" which gives you a live view of what each port is doing.

I'd like to run the "l" command from a script once every minute, and have the output saved into a text file.  I read through this post: [Save "Screen" (program) output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208001/save-screen-program-output-to-a-file) but wasn't able to get it working.  In other searches, I found people have had problems with Minicom logging and seemed like that was advised against.

Anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: *"people have had problems with Minicom logging"*  -- I for one have not had any issues with the logging capabilities of `minicom` (over the course of several years of use).  So perhaps you should not be so quick to dismiss that as a solution.  Can you provide some of those search results that had `minicom` logging issues?

Comment: I'll try to dig it up, but the primary reason it was advised against was that it writes the log when the session ends, not on a continuous basis.