# Record only single instance of screen(program) to a file using linux script

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I am working on a production environment which uses linux [screen](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) to manage output. It has 8 instances names as 1$ bash, 2$ bash and so on. I want to store output of one instance to a file and was referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208001/save-screen-program-output-to-a-file) stackoverflow discussion (Edit section of question provides the solution). Till now, in order to reconnect my screen I do following:

```
screen -r 24813
```

where 24813 is session id.

And the screen instance I want to connect to is at pts/2 (I get this using who -aH).

In order to record only single instance(pts/2) I think I need to run:

```
script output.txt
```

and then some command to connect to only one instance(pts/2) of screen like:

```
screen -r 24813/dev/pts/2
```

or

```
screen /dev/pts/2 24813
```

Though I am not able to figure out how to record  output of pts/2 only. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can't you run `script` inside the screen session?

Comment: Thanks. I had tried tee from inside screen but didn't tried script. For the record one has to use flush option (-f) along with script otherwise output won't be written to file promptly