# Starting Linux Screen Session with Nodejs Spawn

Tags: node.js, linux, spawn

I am currently working on a web admin panel system for managing game servers for a particular game and mod. I wish to implement in the panel a feature to allow you to start and stop the servers individually by clicking start and stop buttons.

To be able to label the server processes and their children such that I can find them again later to kill I am using Linux screens and labelling them. I am using nodejs's spawn command to start the screen. As shown here:

```
  console.log(`screen -m -d -S serverscreen${server.id} wine ${(args.disableWSE === true) ? 'mb_warband_dedicated.exe' : 'WSELoaderServer.exe'} -r "Configs/${args.config}" -m "${args.module}"`);


  const program = spawn(
    'screen',
    [
      '-m', '-d',
      '-S', `serverscreen${server.id}`,
      'wine',
        (args.disableWSE === true) ? 'mb_warband_dedicated.exe' : 'WSELoaderServer.exe',
        '-r', `Configs/${args.config}`,
        '-m', `${args.module}`
    ],
    {
      cwd: currentGameserverPath,
      detached: true,
      stdio: 'ignore'
    }
  );
```

However, I am facing an issue that I have exhausted all my knowledge on trying to solve. The command does not work when used in the spawn, i.e. I can run the command shown in the `console.log` into the `cwd` directory and the gameserver will happily start, however, when the spawn command is called the screen does not start. I have logged stderr and stdout and both are empty and the spawn exits with `0`.

Any suggestions?

For greater context, here is the remainder of the function that encapsulates this code snippet:

```
export default async (parent, args, context) => {
  /* Check for Permissions */
  if (context.user === null)
    throw new Error('You must be logged in to complete this action.');

  const requestingAdmin = await AdminPermission.findOne({
    server: args.serverID,
    admin: context.user
  });

  if (requestingAdmin === null)
    throw new Error('You do not have permission to do that.');

  const server = await Server.findOne({
    id: args.serverID
  });
  if(server === null) throw new Error('Server not found.');

  const currentGameserverPath = path.join(
    require.resolve('gameservers'),
    `../${server.id}`
  );
  if (!fs.existsSync(currentGameserverPath))
    throw new Error('Server folder does not exist!');


  const executablePath = path.join(
    currentGameserverPath,
    (args.disableWSE === true) ? '/mb_warband_dedicated.exe' : '/WSELoaderServer.exe'
  );
  if (!fs.existsSync(executablePath)) throw new Error('Executable does not exist!');

  const moduleFolder = path.join(currentGameserverPath, `/Modules/${args.module}`);
  if (!fs.existsSync(moduleFolder)) throw new Error('Module does not exist!');

  let configFile = path.join(currentGameserverPath, `/Configs/${args.config}`);
  if (!fs.existsSync(configFile)) throw new Error('Config does not exist!');

  console.log(`screen -m -d -S serverscreen${server.id} wine ${(args.disableWSE === true) ? 'mb_warband_dedicated.exe' : 'WSELoaderServer.exe'} -r "Configs/${args.config}" -m "${args.module}"`);


  const program = spawn(
    'screen',
    [
      '-m', '-d',
      '-S', `serverscreen${server.id}`,
      'wine',
        (args.disableWSE === true) ? 'mb_warband_dedicated.exe' : 'WSELoaderServer.exe',
        '-r', `Configs/${args.config}`,
        '-m', `${args.module}`
    ],
    {
      cwd: currentGameserverPath,
      detached: true,
      stdio: 'ignore'
    }
  );

  program.unref();


  server.gameserverLastModule = args.module;
  server.gameserverLastConfig = args.config;
  await server.save();

  return server;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a new lead whilst browsing SO:

- [Using `-L` will create a log file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208001/save-screen-program-output-to-a-file)
- The log file contained, `wine: /home/tsm/.wine is not owned by you`.
- [The resolution to that is to do `sudo chown -R root: ~/.wine`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894877/wine-is-not-owned-by-you-am-i-safe/894878#894878). This is because I am running the web server as root to get port 80 perms, so it starts wine as root, so root must own the `.wine` folder.