# Terminal log export in vscode remote ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, logging, ssh, terminal, event-tracking

I am using remote ssh from vscode to connect my Linux machines which is working fine. But I need to save my remote ssh session log in vscode terminal automatically for every ssh session I am going to use from vscode.
Can you please someone help me to fix this issue as soon as possible?
It is something like putty logging.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode does not offer a built-in way to log the terminal session, unfortunately. You could achieve this on shell level, though, for example using [`screen`](https://opensource.com/article/17/3/introduction-gnu-screen) with its [`-L` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22227825/3018229) or [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) along with the [tmux-logging](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-logging) plugin.