# Gnu Screen hardcopy without joining screen

Tags: macos, bash, gnu-screen

I writing a python app that runs some commands on a gnu screen without joining the screen and seeing the hardcopy buffer. In particular, I am running:

```
screen -dmS test
screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff "ls$(printf \\r)"
screen -S test -X hardcopy screenOutput.txt
```

when I look at screenOutput.txt, I see nothing.

However, if I join the screen, and then run hardcopy,

```
screen -dmS test
screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff "ls$(printf \\r)"
screen -r test
(quit the screen with c-A c-D)
screen -S test -X hardcopy screenOutput.txt
```

Then I see the output in screenOutput.txt.

Is there a way to get hardcopy to write to the file, without joining the screen?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807474/copying-gnu-screen-scrollback-buffer-to-file-extended-hardcopy

Comment: This works with version 4.03.01, any idea how to get it to work with 4.00.03?

Comment: Looking at the git log, [there have been a few fixes for `hardcopy` since 2006](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/log/?qt=grep&q=hardcopy), so it may very well be broken in`4.00.03`. You might wish to step through the source to check if it writes bogus data or just takes a wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

See [linux - Send command to detached screen and get the output - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110055/send-command-to-detached-screen-and-get-the-output) for an example on how to send commands to a session. One correct invocation is:

```
screen -dmS test
screen -S test -X hardcopy screenOutput.txt
```

I.e. `-X` shall be *the first command option.* `-d`/`-r` switches to search only attached/detached sessions have to *follow* it (the docs are notoriously vague on this); in this case, they are not needed at all.

I confirmed this to not work (produce blank file) in `screen` `v4.0.3` and work in `v4.2.0` and up in the same environment.

**Extensive investigation:**

Debugging shows that the root cause is in `WriteFile` at `fileio.c:472` : `if (!fore) break;` which quits the function without writing anything because `fore` (a pointer to the foreground window) is indeed `NULL`.
I couldn't pinpoint the specific commit where this was fixed, but did check that it isn't `NULL` in `v4.2.0`. The variable is set in a number of places around the codebase and is reset to `NULL` in roughly the same amount of places, often in code that follows the assignment. So the chances of a working workaround are very slim.

I hereby reaffirm that in `screen` `v4.0.3`, `hardcopy` is broken and you have to upgrade (e.g. install a version to `/usr/local` so that it overrides the stock one).

Comment: If I run the first two commands (but change the -r to the -S), I still get nothing in the screenOutput.txt file.

Comment: @user1763510 WFM with the code in the answer. `screen v4.03.01`

Comment: Strange, I am on OSX 10.10.5.  Are you on linux?  Seems like it wouldn't make a difference. `Screen version 4.00.03`

Comment: Just tried on Linux with `Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06`, still doesn't work.