# How do I increase the scrollback buffer in a running screen session?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Lets say I have a currently running [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) session I am interacting with through putty.  I've realized that the scrollback buffer is too small and would like to increase it *without* starting a new screen session.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just in case someone wants to increase the scrollback buffer *when* starting a new session: `screen -h <numlines>`

Answer (score 203, accepted):

The [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) explains that you can enter command line mode in a running session by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, then issuing the `scrollback <num>` command.

Comment: You'll have to do for each window of the current screen individually.

Comment: where `<num>` is the number of lines of scrollback

Comment: If you find you reach the default max buffer can't show more history, and setting by `scrollback <num>`, it doesn't help you extand buffer anymore, you need redo last command to get the whole history buffer.

Answer (score 440):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd> and then type

```
scrollback 10000
```

to get a 10000 line buffer, for example.

You can also set the default number of scrollback lines by adding

```
defscrollback 10000
```

to your `~/.screenrc` file.

To scroll (if your terminal doesn't allow you to by default), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then scroll (with the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for next page or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for previous page, or just with your mouse wheel / two-fingers). To exit the scrolling mode, just press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Another tip: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>I</kbd> shows your current buffer setting.

Comment: +1 for the hint with the defscrollback which is set to 1024 in Ubuntu 12.10 (which I have to use at work).

Comment: `byobu-screen` on Ubuntu 12.04 seems to set the defscrollback to 10000

Comment: I wanted to point out that if your screenrc opens additional terms for you, you need to put the defscrollback before the windows are opened, or else they will just get the default 1024

Comment: it's not working on a mac. I put `startup_message off' and 'defscrollback 5000' into my newly created `~/.screenrc` and it is getting the first line, but the second one seems to be ignored.

Comment: I use the screen scrollback buffer a lot. I often realize after the fact, that I should have redirected that to a log file rather than just printing something. I then do Ctrl-a :hardcopy -h log.txt to save the entire scrollback buffer (which I have set to 100000 by default) into the file and this is often enough to capture everything interesting. I could not work without screen.

Comment: @chizou you made my day!!! "put the defscrollback before the windows are opened" !!!

Answer (score 20):

As Already mentioned we have two ways.

### Per screen (session) interactive setting

And it's done interactively, and takes effect immediately.

<kbd>CTRL + A</kbd> followed by <kbd>:</kbd> And we type `scrollback 1000000` And hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You detach from the screen and come back, it will be always the same.

You open another new screen, and the value is reset again to default. So it's not a global setting!

### And the permanent default setting

Which is done by adding `defscrollback 1000000` to `.screenrc` (in home)

`defscrollback` and not `scrollback` (def stand for default)

What you need to know is if the file is not created, **You create it** !

```bash
> cd ~ && vim .screenrc
```

And you add `defscrollback 1000000` to it.

Or in one command

```bash
> echo "defscrollback 1000000" >> ~/.screenrc
```

(if not created already)

#### Taking effect

When you add the default to `.screenrc`, the already running screen at re-attach will not take effect! The `.screenrc` run at the screen creation, and it makes sense! Just as with a normal console and shell launch.

All the new created screens will have the set value.

### Checking the screen effective buffer size

To check type <kbd>CTRL + A</kbd> followed by <kbd>i</kbd>

And The result will be as

[image]

Importantly the **buffer size** is the number after the **+ sign**
(in the illustration i set it to 1 000 000)

Note too that when you change it interactively. The effect is immediate and take over the default value.

## Scrolling

<kbd>CTRL+ A</kbd> followed by <kbd>ESC</kbd> (to enter the copy mode).

Then navigate with <kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>PgUp</kbd> <kbd>PgDown</kbd>

And <kbd>ESC</kbd> again to quit that mode.

(Extra info: to copy hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to start selecting, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again to copy, simple and cool)

Now the buffer is bigger!

And that's sum it up for the important details.

Comment: Great to know steps of how to scroll !

Comment: thanks. learned a new trick to check screen buffer size using:  CTRL + A followed by i

Answer (score 11):

There is a minimal amount of "default" buffer when you startup a 'screen' session within your 'putty session'. I use screens a lot in my work, so I can tell you that you will not have a combination of 'screen' buffer & 'putty' buffer within your 'screen' session.

Setting the default number of scrollback lines by adding `defscrollback 10000`
to your `~/.screenrc` file is the correct solution.

By the way, I use "defscrollback 200000" in my `./screenrc` file.

Answer (score 8):

```
WARNING: setting this value too high may cause your system to experience a significant hiccup. 
The higher the value you set, the more virtual memory is allocated to the screen process when initiating the screen session.
```

I set my ~/.screenrc to "defscrollback 123456789" and when I initiated a screen, my entire system froze up for a good 10 minutes before coming back to the point that I was able to kill the screen process (which was consuming 16.6GB of VIRT mem by then).

Answer (score 0):

Put the defscrollback before additional windows are opened in your ~/.screenrc file, e.g.

```
# ===============================================================
# VARIABLES - Number values
# ===============================================================
defscrollback         10000          # default: 100

# ===============================================================
# STARTUP of programs in an extra window:
# ===============================================================
screen -t da 0 
screen -t da 1 
screen -t da 2 
screen -t da 3 
screen -t da 4 
screen -t da 5 
screen -t da 6 
screen -t da 7 
screen -t da 8
screen -t da 9
```

Otherwise, you will have only 1024 lines in the history buffer.