# How to increase the size of the scrollback buffer in GNU screen

Tags: gnu-screen

How do I increase the number of lines that I can view in `screen`?

I want to view the lines from the point when I ran `screen -S <screen_name>` to the current operation. For example, how would I increase the buffer length to around 50000 lines?

I have already tried `^a :scrollback <number>` but it does not increases the lines I can reach in my current terminal.

Comment: wont easiest be to use a tee or redirect (>) to save the results to a file ? and use less to view the file ?

Comment: Removed reference to PuTTY because it doesn't appear to be relevant to the question. @gnuyoga: `screen` can also log any window to a file with the `logfile <filename>` (default: `screen.log`) and `log` (toggle on/off) commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the scrollback buffer in a running screen session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760346/how-do-i-increase-the-scrollback-buffer-in-a-running-screen-session)

Answer (score 12):

You cannot retroactively increase the scrollback buffer length in the current session in order to recover old lines that have already been discarded. However, if you change the current `scrollback` parameter setting (`C-a :scrollback <number>`), it will add more space for future terminal output. You can also set the `defscrollback` parameter to affect the initial `scrollback` setting for new windows.

If you want to set the default for all windows of all new `screen` sessions, make a `~/.screenrc` file with

```
defscrollback 50000
```

or, if you only want a big scrollback sometimes, put it in a separate file, like `~/screenrc-50k-scrollback` and invoke `screen` like this:

```
screen -S <screen_name> -c ~/screenrc-50k-scrollback
```

Check the current scrollback buffer capacity with `C-a i` (the `info` command).

```
(22,1)/(25,40)+50000 +flow G0[BBBB] 0(bash)
               ^^^^^
```

Reference: [GNU Screen manual, Scrollback section](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Scrollback.html#Scrollback)

Comment: for me, on Debian Jessie/testing with screen 4.4, the option in .screenrc is scrollback 50000

Comment: defscrollback for me on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understood correctly what you asked, but if so I think you can just increase the value of `Lines of scrollback` property you can find on the `Window` menu item on the left of your `Session` configuration.

Comment: The question was modified, my answer was related to original question.