# How to catch Java application output (System.out.println()) when connected to remote host (OS Solaris) via Putty and connection is lost?

Tags: java, solaris

How to catch Java application output (`System.out.println()`) when connected to remote host (OS Solaris) via Putty if remote session is lost and connected again? Java application on remote host was started like this:

> java -jar /SomeApplication.jar &

Now the output is visible. But if I exit remote session and connect again - no more output is visible, though the same java application is still running - I can see it by issuing this command:

> ps -ef | grep java

Output is:

> root 5221     1   0 20:04:15 ?           1:20 java -jar
>   SomeApplication.jar

The application ID is 5221 and it is running, but it's output vanishes somewhere..

Comment: Its output "vanishes" into its original TTY. Consider using `nohup` or teeing output to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and neat suggestion is running the application in a `screen` session (check the Solaris package).

First, you launch screen:

```
$ screen
```

Then you launch the application **inside `screen`**, like usual:

```
$ java -jar /SomeApplication.jar
```

And you are set. You don't need the trailing `&`: you can detach (see below) and log out; the screen session will be kept running. On next login, just issue:

```
$ screen -x
```

and the session, with its output, will be *reattached*.

A quick reference:

- Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> (first <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> together, then <kbd>d</kbd>) to *detach* from the session, so that you leave the `screen` session (with the java application running inside), go back to the Solaris shell and do other things -- including logging out graciously.
- Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> to enter "copy mode", so that you can scroll up and down and <kbd>q</kbd> to leave copy mode.

There are many other useful features, just read a quick intro :)

Comment: No, still no luck.. If I exit terminal, and connect again, then `screen -x`, I get this message: There is no screen to be attached.

Comment: Be careful not to leave the `screen` terminal instead of the Solaris login shell. Correct sequence is: launch `screen`, launch `java` inside, `CTRL+a d` to detach and then logout.

Comment: Wow, that's great :) It's working. My question is - is it (I mean Screen) using Solaris resources if session is terminated and the application still working? For example - if the output is continuous?

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean by "Solaris resources", could you please clarify? Regarding output: yes, it's continuosly printed to the `screen` tty, so that if you detach and reattach, you will find anything that was printed during your absence. Still, the buffer is not infinite, you can increase its size (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760346/how-do-i-increase-the-scrollback-buffer-in-a-running-screen-session), for instance), but if you need a complete log, I suggest piping output to `tee`, like `java -jar /SomeApplication.jar | tee -a logfile`

Comment: Regarding logging, if you have time, please consider refactoring the application so that it uses a proper logging framework, [logback through slf4j](http://logback.qos.ch/) is a great choice (and it's free/open source too).

Comment: By resources I mean the memory. Now I understand - everything depends on buffer size. Thanks indeed for help.

Answer (score 1):

Log files play better in these scenarios.And sysouts are expensive operations too.
Or when you start the java program, redirect error/outputs to a temp file. So you can view it later.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but for quick testing it is enough sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

`java -jar /SomeApplication.jar > wherever_you_want_output.log 2>&1 &`

the > redirects system.out.println to the file, the 2>&1 sends the system.err.println to the same file (you could also put `2> error_file.log` to get a separate System.err.println() output.

Long term though you should use a logging framework through like log4j or the java logging framework.

If you want to watch the output then as it grows, you can do a `tail -f whatever_you_want_output.log`